# How to get AEC model data in autodesk forge?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, forge

I want to add new Autodesk Forge Minimap3DExtension to my forge viewer, but i can't get AECModelData with doc.downloadAecModelData(). 
I try to get data with this code is it right?

`````
            var viewables = viewerApp1.bubble.search({'type':'geometry'});
            if (viewables.length === 0) {
                console.error('Document contains no viewables.');
                return;
            }

           //explicitly call downloadAecModelData of viewer document.
            doc.downloadAecModelData()
}````

I also try to get data with bubbleNode, but got only errors.
`````

Answer (score 1):

Only RVT files from Revit 2018 and later will produce the `AecModelData`. Please check your RVT file version. If it is supported, you can use either way below to get `AecModelData`

```
// From document
await doc.downloadAecModelData()

// From bubble
await Autodesk.Viewing.Document.getAecModelData(viewer.model.getDocumentNode())
```